# Algorithm for python do-while loop

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, do-while, pseudocode

```
while True:         #exception loop
    try:
        NumOfPpl=raw_input('Enter the number of people: ')
        NumOfPpl=int(NumOfPpl)
        break       #for early exit the loop if num is an integer
    except ValueError:
        print ("\nPlease make sure you key in number only! \n\tand please do not leave blank!")
print "\nIs there any of theese person present?: \n\tA. Disabled \n\tB. 65-years-old and above \n\tC. None for Both A. and B. \n"
```

Above is only a fragment of my code. What I want to know is, how to write it in algorithm and pseudocode version? Or even for flowchart as requested for school assignment. Please and thank you.

Comment: A pseudocode version pretty much means to re-write this in a sort of "plain english" that is meant to be understood by "humans" only and not to be parsed by a computer. There is no "proper" syntax to use - just as long as it makes sense to the person reading it.

Comment: Do you understand the current code? What each command does and how the application flow operates? By application flow I mean in which order the commands will be executed...

Comment: There must be examples of pseudocode in your textbook.  Imitate them.

Comment: there's no textbook in my school (real poor environment), so naturally nothing to refer to. But I'm not quite sure about the flow of this code so I can't write it in correct order.

Comment: based on my understanding, the pseudocode is
while NumOfPpl is not integer
    get NumOfPpl(as raw input)
    if NumOfPpl is integer
    end loop
if NumOfPpl is not integer
    print ("error")
else:
    continue